# SQL Server : recreate table in appropriate order

Tags: sql-server

I've deleted some records (more precisely row 4) from a table in a SQL Server database. Now the first column goes like this (1,2,3,5) without row 4:

```
       ID Name
       ------------
       1   Luk
       2   Sky
       3   Philips
       5   Andrey
```

How can I recreate this table and insert all data again in appropriate order?

Like this:

```
       ID Name
       --------
       1   Luk
       2   Sky
       3   Philips
       4   Andrey
```

**EDIT:**

But if i have another column (number) that is not a key, like this:

```
       ID Number Name
       ------------
       1    1      Luk
       2    2      Sky
       3    3      Philips
       5    5      Andrey
```

Then can i recreate column Number and Name,

```
         ID Number Name
       ------------
       1    1      Luk
       2    2      Sky
       3    3      Philips
       5    4      Andrey          'Can i do this, and if can HOW?
```

Comment: **DON'T DO IT!!!!** IDENTITY columns should not hold any meaning, therefore it should not matter that you have gaps. Furthermore, I would guess that `ID` is your primary key too, and primary keys should not change once they have been created, do you really want to cascade the change of ID 5 to ID 4 throughout your entire database? If you just want the order of the records with no gaps for display purposes use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID)`

Comment: Strongly agree with GarethD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a pretty strong case for never storing this number, since it is calculated, instead you could just create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.YourView
AS
SELECT  ID,
        Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID),
        Name
FROM    dbo.YourTable;
GO
```

This way after you have deleted rows, your view will already be in sync without having to perform any updates.

If you need to store the value, then almost the same query applies, but just placed inside a common table expression, which is then updated:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  ID, 
            Number, 
            NewNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID)
    FROM    dbo.YourTable
)
UPDATE  CTE
SET     Number = NewNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dbcc command

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('tableName', RESEED, 0)
```

It would reset identity to 0.

**Note** it would require to truncate table first.

Comment: @Nik update query like `UPDATE tableName SET Number = 4 where Number = 5`? Is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the ID to auto increment which by default, the starting value for AUTO_INCREMENT is 1, and it will increment by 1 for each new record.

E.g MSSQL uses IDENTITY keyword to auto increment whereas MySQL uses the AUTO_INCREMENT keyword to perform an auto-increment feature.

MSSQL

`ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY`

MySQL 

`ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`